# Flexslider not working properly on ipad/iphone

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I have 2 flexsliders on 1 site. Both have different IDs, both have a flexslider bound to them, with different settings: 1 element has slideshow set to true, the second element has slideshow set to false.

On PC, this works as expected.

On iPad and iPhone and Android, both sliders slideshow automatically. What a horrible problem!

Anyone has any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just disable not-working touchstart

```
// slider.eventType = ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
  slider.eventType = "click";
```

Answer (score 0):

If using the Avada Theme:

Flexislider > Settings

**Control Settings**

*UN*-TICK the option [ ]  Enable the touch swipe navigation on touch-screen devices